# C# : Data collection to keep string?

Tags: c#, string, data-collection

Any Data Collection to keep the strings?
I want to know any other data collection that can keep string, because enum cannot keep string.

Comment: Most collections can store any type of object. The difference between each type of collection is how those objects are stored/written/accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string>
```

Or

```
StringCollection
```

Should do...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: It's better to use a generic collection rather then non-generic, isn't it? You can use LINQ, etc without addition operations

Comment: @abatishchev - maybe a little, but I wouldn't get excited either way.

Answer (score 1):

How about `ICollection<string>` or `List<string>` or a static array of strings (`string[]`)?

Answer (score 1):

System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection

Comment: It isn't generic. Rather better to use a generic collection.

Comment: @abatishchev - while generally true, It is a bit subjective

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with WPF or Silverlight and need to databind to it then you should use

```
ObservableCollection<string>
```

Although I should point out that string is not mutable.